# z-index issue in Internet explorer 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

I am using a drop-down list using jquery when the user hover the main menu it will drop down and its working fine in all browsers except the IE7 and below i am using z-index to display the drop-down menu in-front of all elements but its wont works.

[image]

the menu items(dummydummy) goes behind the textbox and the button

style of the submenu items is

```
#sub-menu {

z-index: 1000;
}
```

and the textbox and buttons are grouped inside a div and the div's style is

```
#grouped {
left: 100px;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say for sure without seeing the complete markup and css (or better, a fiddle with just the code required to reproduce the issue), but try giving the **parent** of the `#sub-menu` element `position: relative` and `z-index: 2`

Comment: post your full markup or a test page so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**z-index** only work with position `relative`, `absolute` & `fixed`. So, Give `position:relative` to your `#submenu`. Write like this:

```
#sub-menu {
 position:relative;
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommending trying out CSS3 Pie.  We started using it and many of the IE7 wacky bugs disappeared.

http://css3pie.com/

I was amazed at the things that css3pie fixed in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try applying higher z-index values to your #sub-menu ul and li values. This has worked on a superfish menu that was giving me the same problems in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
#sub-menu {
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#grouped {
left: 100px;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```